# Custom Image for Bokeh Plot and App Page

Tags: image, plot, customization, bokeh

I would like to add a custom image to the top of the page in my Bokeh App. How do I do that in the Python code without modifying the html file?

I was able to remove the Bokeh logo from just right above plot by setting the Plot attribute `logo=None` but now, how do I fill this with another image?

Comment: Any update on this guys ?

Comment: The same, any update ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that's current supported.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. This issue [link](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues/4008) is still open.